# "JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed", Why this message is occurred? How can I fix this issue

Tags: mongodb, express

This is my code
While I execute the code this "Not authorized, token failed" message is showing from the front end.

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/Staff.Model");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => { 
    let token

    if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
       try{
           token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

        req.user =  await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')

        next()
       }catch (error){
           console.error(error)
           res.status(401)
           throw new Error('Not authorized, token failed')
       }
    }

    if(!token) {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('Not authorized, no token')
    }
})
```

Comment: And what is `console.error(error)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. The Only solution I solved this after much mind crack. you just need to use the keyword " return " before every " res ".I hope this will work for others too.